# os.walk set start and end point - python

Tags: python-2.7, datetime, argparse, os.walk

I'm trying to find how to stop a os.walk after it has walked through a particular file.

I have a directory of log files organized by date. I'm trying to replace grep searches allowing a user to find ip addresses stored in a date range they specify.

The program will take the following arguments:

-i ipv4 or ipv6 address with subnet

-s start date ie 2013/12/20 matches file structure

-e end date

I'm assuming because the topdown option their is a logic that should allow me to declare a endpoint, what is the best way to do this? I'm thinking while loop.

I apologize in advance if something is off with my question. Just checked blood sugar, it's low 56, gd type one.

---

Additional information

The file structure will be situated in flows/index_border as such

2013

--01

--02

----01

----...

----29

2014

___________Hope this is clear, year folder contains month folders, containing day folders, containing hourly files. Dates increase downwards.___________________

The end date will need to be inclusive, ( I didn't focus too much on it because I can just add code to move one day up)

---

I have been trying to make a date range function, I was surprised I didn't see this in any datetime docs, seems like it would be useful.

---

```
import os, gzip, netaddr, datetime, argparse
startDir = '.'
def sdate_format(s):
    try:
        return (datetime.datetime.strptime(s, '%Y/%m/%d').date())
    except ValueError:
        msg = "Bad start date. Please use yyyy/mm/dd format."
        raise argparse.ArgumentTypeError(msg)
def edate_format(e):
    try:
        return (datetime.datetime.strptime(e, '%Y/%m/%d').date())
    except ValueError:
        msg = "Bad end date. Please use yyyy/mm/dd format."
        raise argparse.ArgumentTypeError(msg)

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Locate IP address in log files for a particular date or date range')
parser.add_argument('-s', '--start_date', action='store', type=sdate_format, dest='start_date', help='The first date in range of interest.')
parser.add_argument('-e', '--end_date', action='store', type=edate_format, dest='end_date', help='The last date in range of interest.')
parser.add_argument('-i', action='store', dest='net', help='IP address or address range, IPv4 or IPv6 with optional subnet accepted.', required=True)

results = parser.parse_args()
start = results.start_date
end = results.end_date
target_ip = results.net
startDir = '/flows/index_border/{0}/{1:02d}/{2:02d}'.format(start.year, start.month, start.day)

print('searching...')
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(startDir):
    for contents in files:
        if contents.endswith('.gz'):
            f = gzip.open(os.path.join(root, contents), 'r')
        else:
            f = open(os.path.join(root, contents), 'r')
            text = f.readlines()
            f.close()
            for line in text:
                for address_item in netaddr.IPNetwork(target_IP):
                    if str(address_item) in line:
                        print line,
```

Comment: Not sure to understand what the criterion to stop should be. Should it be the first matching item? (Check if `walk()` walks the directories in a predictible order or not, to ensure consistency in your results). More generally, an example of a simple directory/files structure and what you would like to get as a result from this example, but what is not working yet, would be welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to describe what works or does not work.  The `argparse` of your code looks fine, though I haven't done any testing.  The use of `type` is refreshingly correct. :)   (posters often misuse that parameter.)

But as for the `stopping`, I'm guessing you could do:

```
endDir = '/flows/index_border/{0}/{1:02d}/{2:02d}'.format(end.year, end.month, end.day)

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(startDir):
    for contents in files:
        ....
    if endDir in <something based on dirs and files>:
         break
```

I don't know enough your file structure to be more specific.  It's also been sometime since I worked with `os.walk`.  In any case, I think a conditional `break` is the way to stop the walk early.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os, gzip, netaddr, datetime, argparse, sys
searchDir = '.'
searchItems = []
def sdate_format(s):
    try:
        return (datetime.datetime.strptime(s, '%Y/%m/%d').date())
    except ValueError:
        msg = "Bad start date. Please use yyyy/mm/dd format."
        raise argparse.ArgumentTypeError(msg)
def edate_format(e):
    try:
        return (datetime.datetime.strptime(e, '%Y/%m/%d').date())
    except ValueError:
        msg = "Bad end date. Please use yyyy/mm/dd format."
        raise argparse.ArgumentTypeError(msg)


parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Locate IP address in log files for a particular date or date range')
parser.add_argument('-s', '--start_date', action='store', type=sdate_format, dest='start_date',
                        help='The first date in range of interest.', required=True)
parser.add_argument('-e', '--end_date', action='store', type=edate_format, dest='end_date',
                        help='The last date in range of interest.', required=True)
parser.add_argument('-i', action='store', dest='net',
                        help='IP address or address range, IPv4 or IPv6 with optional subnet accepted.', required=True)

results = parser.parse_args()
start = results.start_date
end = results.end_date + datetime.timedelta(days=1)
target_IP = results.net
dateRange = end - start
for addressOfInterest in(netaddr.IPNetwork(target_IP)):
    searchItems.append(str(addressOfInterest))
print('searching...')

for eachDay in range(dateRange.days):
    period = start+datetime.timedelta(days=eachDay)
    searchDir =  '/flows/index_border/{0}/{1:02d}/{2:02d}'.format(period.year, period.month, period.day)

for contents in os.listdir(searchDir):
    if contents.endswith('.gz'):
        f = gzip.open(os.path.join(searchDir, contents), 'rb')
        text = f.readlines()
        f.close()

    else:
        f = open(os.path.join(searchDir, contents), 'r')
        text = f.readlines()
        f.close()
#for line in text:
 #   break

for addressOfInterest in searchItems:
    for line in text:
        if addressOfInterest in line:
       # if str(address_item) in line:
            print contents
            print line,
```

I was banging my head, because I thought I was printing a duplicate. Turns out the file I was given to test has duplication. I ended up removing os.walk due to the predictable nature of the file system, but @hpaulj did provide a correct solution. Much appreciated!